# CiviCRM profiles / Caldera Forms: What to use when?

Tags: profile, caldera-forms

I am new to CiviCRM and CiviCRM profiles and Caldera Forms + CiviCRM seem to be two realisations for the same thing: Let users enter data.

What are the advantages of the realisations? When to use what?

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the same, but the information at this link comparing drupal civicrm webform to profiles might be a similar starting point:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/webform/#compared-to-civicrm-profiles